# Tensorflow ImportError - DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, avx

First thing to report is that I have a CPU *without AVX support*. So I have bought GeForce GTX1060 to be able to run Tensorflow, but unfortunately I cannot get it to work. I am getting this:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I have installed:

- most recent GPU driver: 417.35
- NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit with CUDA v10.0
- cudnn-10.0

I have Python 3.6.8 on Anaconda. Win10 x64. Not sure why on initiating Python I see reference to win32. I suppose it is not the root cause but reporting just in case.

```
 Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 18:50:55) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I have tried both tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0 and 1.10.0. Both give me DLL errors. I have been experimenting with different packages so maybe some dependencies are broken but stacktrace gives no information to me being Python newbie.

This is the stacktrace I am getting when importing tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

And this is for tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

This is the "pip list" result:

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ----------
absl-py                  0.6.1
alabaster                0.7.12
asn1crypto               0.24.0
astor                    0.7.1
astroid                  2.1.0
Babel                    2.6.0
backcall                 0.1.0
bleach                   3.0.2
certifi                  2018.11.29
cffi                     1.11.5
chardet                  3.0.4
cloudpickle              0.6.1
colorama                 0.4.1
cryptography             2.4.2
decorator                4.3.0
docutils                 0.14
entrypoints              0.2.3
gast                     0.2.0
grpcio                   1.16.1
h5py                     2.8.0
idna                     2.8
imagesize                1.1.0
ipykernel                5.1.0
ipython                  7.2.0
ipython-genutils         0.2.0
isort                    4.3.4
jedi                     0.13.2
Jinja2                   2.10
jsonschema               2.6.0
jupyter-client           5.2.4
jupyter-core             4.4.0
Keras                    2.2.4
Keras-Applications       1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing      1.0.5
keyring                  17.0.0
lazy-object-proxy        1.3.1
Markdown                 3.0.1
MarkupSafe               1.1.0
mccabe                   0.6.1
mistune                  0.8.4
mkl-fft                  1.0.6
mkl-random               1.0.2
nbconvert                5.3.1
nbformat                 4.4.0
numpy                    1.14.5
numpydoc                 0.8.0
packaging                18.0
pandocfilters            1.4.2
parso                    0.3.1
pickleshare              0.7.5
pip                      18.1
prompt-toolkit           2.0.7
protobuf                 3.6.1
psutil                   5.4.8
pycodestyle              2.4.0
pycparser                2.19
pyflakes                 2.0.0
Pygments                 2.3.1
pylint                   2.2.2
pyOpenSSL                18.0.0
pyparsing                2.3.0
pyreadline               2.1
PySocks                  1.6.8
python-dateutil          2.7.5
pytz                     2018.7
pywin32                  223
PyYAML                   3.13
pyzmq                    17.1.2
QtAwesome                0.5.3
qtconsole                4.4.3
QtPy                     1.5.2
requests                 2.21.0
rope                     0.11.0
scipy                    1.1.0
setuptools               39.1.0
six                      1.11.0
snowballstemmer          1.2.1
Sphinx                   1.8.2
sphinxcontrib-websupport 1.1.0
spyder                   3.3.2
spyder-kernels           0.3.0
tensorboard              1.12.2
tensorflow-gpu           1.12.0
termcolor                1.1.0
testpath                 0.4.2
tornado                  5.1.1
traitlets                4.3.2
typed-ast                1.1.0
urllib3                  1.24.1
wcwidth                  0.1.7
webencodings             0.5.1
Werkzeug                 0.14.1
wheel                    0.32.3
win-inet-pton            1.0.1
wincertstore             0.2
wrapt                    1.10.11
```

Somebody please give me a hint in which dirtection to check. I have seen many suggestions in different fora to install all different versions and builds of tensorflow, different CUDA versions or other options but before I get to these lengthy procedures I would like to know if it makes sense at all. Maybe lack of AVX at CPU is a blocker that makes all the effort futile.

And one more thing - at one moment, when I had both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu installed (not sure about versions) I have uninstalled plain tensorflow and then the command "**import tensorflow as tf**" ran without errors. Unfortunately at next step "**from tensorflow import keras**" I have got information from Python that keras could not be found. No further tests allowed me to repeat this.

I suppose this is all. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend using CUDA Toolkit: CUDA 9.0. Instead of 10.0 for Tensorflow on Windows. Be sure to uninstall 10.0 and restart your PC otherwise it may not downgrade the CUDA version.

Comment: With no other suggestions available I did exactly that - I uninstalled CUDA 10.0, restarted and installed CUDA 9.0. Nothing changed. Importing Tensorflow 1.12.0 gives the same error as previously.

Comment: Sorry, i meant to suggest 8.0, You need to install Cuda Toolkit 8.0 and cuDNN v5.1 as the GPU version works best with these. I was able to install mine using the instructions here [link](https://medium.com/@viveksingh.heritage/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-version-with-jupyter-windows-10-in-8-easy-steps-8797547028a4)